# Swift downcasting and protocol variables

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a swift protocol that contains one property:

```
protocol WireframeProtocol: class
{
    var rootViewController: UIViewController  { get }
}
```

I then have a class that implements this protocol as such:

```
class MenuWireframe : WireframeProtocol
{
    let rootViewController: UIViewController

    init()
    {
        self.rootViewController = MenuViewController(nibName: "MenuViewController", bundle: nil)
        (self.rootViewController as! MenuViewController).presenter = MenuPresenter(interactor: MenuInteractor())
    }
}
```

In my Wireframe class the variable is actually of type MenuViewController but has to instead be declared as UIViewController to confirm to the protocol. I have to use (self.rootViewController as! MenuViewController) to downcast it to the correct class I want so as to be able to access its properties. It is fine in my simple example above but is not very readable, especially in more complex situations. Is there a better way to declare the protocol variable?

Many thanks!

Comment: Since you are using VIPER, you could/should declare your rootviewcontroller as a protocol (the View protocol), and define a weak property there, which will be the presenter.

Comment: Hi Daniel, that is true but it this case is for a different purpose. I wish to have a protocol every wireframe conforms to that exposes a UIViewController I can use for navigation purposes. I suppose I could still use that view protocol for this if the protocol is for UIViewControllers only...mmm I will check that out and get back to you

Comment: @bennythemink have you checked my answer ?

Comment: @zellb lol, checking it now Zellb, will get back to you in a minute

Comment: @DánielNagy good catch recognising that I am using VIPER by the way, I bumped up your comment as a result :) I'm interested in learning what you think of the pattern? As there is not very much information out there for it at the moment.

Comment: @bennythemink Well, I'm learning VIPER as well, but my experience is that it is a very clean approach. Interpreting what one of my colleagues said: good programmers will find a way to write clean, structured code, but VIPER can enforce even bad programmers to write it as well with its modules. And I really like the abstraction that the components talks only(most of the times) throgh protocols, so you can easily change the implementation of the protocol anytime without causing damage.

Comment: @DánielNagy completely agree. It does mean a lot more files but I love that it pushes developers to think more of separation of concerns. If you have come across any good code examples of VIPER architected projects please do share. Many thanks.

Comment: @bennythemink ok, I will share it as soon as I found one!

Comment: Is the accepted answer still working for you on Swift 3? (I'm also building out some VIPER super protocols)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is a better way and thats by using generic protocols. To implement that you must declare your protocol similar like this :

```
protocol WireframeProtocol{

    typealias RootViewController : UIViewController
    var rootViewController: RootViewController  { get }

}
```

then in your adoption class set rootViewController type as MenuViewController

```
class MenuWireframe : WireframeProtocol{

let rootViewController: MenuViewController

    init(){
        self.rootViewController = MenuViewController(nibName: "MenuViewController", bundle: nil)
        self.rootViewController.presenter = MenuPresenter(interactor: MenuInteractor())
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi zellb, that works! But I'm not exactly sure why it does. Can you explain it to me please?

Comment: Type aliases define an alternative name for an existing type, so in this case I declared a new name for all types that are inherited from UIViewController (in line `typealias RootViewController : UIViewController` ) . After that I set  rootViewController type to our newly type so rootViewController var can hold any value created from classes that are inherited from UIViewController, so now on you can set it directly as MenuViewController without any down casting requirements . I hope I was clear

Answer (score 2):

If you can change protocol declaration, use @zelb's answer. If you cannot, you could do something like:

```
class MenuWireframe : WireframeProtocol 
{
    var rootViewController: UIViewController {
        return menuViewController
    }

    let menuViewController: MenuViewController!

    init()
    {
        menuViewController = MenuViewController(...)
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I just tested it and it does not work out I'm afraid. Firstly I cannot use "let" with this approach and secondly I still have to cast rootViewController to type MenuViewController if I wish to access its properties :( but thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @bennythemink Why couldn't you use 'let'? And idea is to access `menuViewController` instead of `rootViewController` where you know that given object is in fact `MenuWireFrame` not arbitrary `WireFrameProtocol`

Comment: Hi, I cannot use "let" as rootViewController is now a computed property in your suggestion. I may be pedantic but it now also means I have two properties instead of one in the class. But again thank you for the tip.

Comment: @JakubVano even changing protocol declaration in my way wont cause any errors at all

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this one :

```
protocol WireframeProtocol: UIViewController {
  var rootViewController: UIViewController  { get }
} 

class MenuWireframe : WireframeProtocol
{
    let rootViewController: WireframeProtocol

    init()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I get a "non class type WireframeProtocol cannot inherit from class UIViewController" :/ Will not work that way I'm afraid. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: yes, I pointed this missing at the beginning of Swift in a project. In Objective-C we could make something like `UIViewController<WireframeProtocol>* rootViewController;` ...