# Reusable views/modules with VIPER

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, viper-architecture

I am new to VIPER and trying to develop a module(1 screen) using the same. The exact screen is used in other module of the app but with some additional features. Just want to know what components of VIPER I can reuse in other module?
Presenter?
Router?
Interactors?
View?

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling the same question, more specifically I want to reuse View part of VIPER. In my app I have ViewController (View in VIPER terms) which is the same for two modules, what is different is actions (in Presenter).

So far I came to the solution based on parent-child protocols (not sure where it's VIPER best practice) - refer very simplified example below

I would also advise to look there (viper and protocol associated types): https://stackoverflow.com/a/30325318/5157022

So the example. This class is holding common functionality I want to share

```
    import UIKit

    protocol CommonPresenterProtocol: class {
        func didSelect(row: Int)
    }

    protocol CommonViewProtocol: class {

    }

    class CommonView: UITableViewController {

        var presenter: CommonPresenterProtocol?

        override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {return 1}
        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {return 4}
        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "\(indexPath.row)", for: indexPath)
        }

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            presenter?.didSelect(row: indexPath.row)
        }

    }

    extension CommonView: CommonViewProtocol {

    }
```

And then here is class which takes that functionality and also add some additional functionality (please note that assigning "presenter = FirstPresenter()" should not happen in viewDidLoad - it's just a simplification for the sake of example)

```
import UIKit

protocol FirstViewProtocol: class {

}

protocol FirstPresenterProtocol: CommonPresenterProtocol { //using parent protocol
    func didDeSelect(row: Int) //adding additional functionality
}

class FirstView: CommonView {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        presenter = FirstPresenter()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        (presenter as! FirstPresenterProtocol).didDeSelect(row: indexPath.row)
    }

}

extension FirstView: FirstViewProtocol {

}
```